# Sending action in livewire

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-livewire

VM131:2 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token

)at index.js:75:58

I am  facing this error when I send any action in laravel livewire when I disable csrf token in verifycsrf middleware it works but login not works how to solve please help anyone
How to solve without disable csrf

Comment: Very hard for us to help you without seeing your actual code.

Comment: Also, disabling your CSRF protection is a terrible idea.